# always app crash when loading ..

Tags: java, android

the code was working fine .. it is a simple calculating app.

unfortunately it stopped working after i changed something .. the problem is I dont know this something ..

this my code ...

```
package com.bogaza.barazileyyecalc;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

//declarations..

final TextView        lbl1 =  (TextView)       findViewById(R.id.textView1); 
final TextView        lbl2 =  (TextView)       findViewById(R.id.textView2);
final EditText        txt1 =  (EditText)       findViewById(R.id.editText1); 
final EditText        txt2 =  (EditText)       findViewById(R.id.editText2);
final Button          btn1 =  (Button)         findViewById(R.id.button1); 
final TextView        lbl3 =  (TextView)       findViewById(R.id.textView3);

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

// click button to get numbers from edittexts and add them to textviews ..      

    btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {   


        public void onClick(View v) {  
            if(v.getId() == R.id.button1){

            int value1 = (int) ((txt1.getText().toString()   
                    .equals("")) ? 0 : Double.valueOf(txt1.getText().toString()));   

            int value2 = (int) ((txt2.getText().toString()   
                    .equals("")) ? 0 : Double.valueOf(txt2.getText().toString()));   

            lbl3.setText(String.valueOf(value1 + value2));
            }
          }   

    });   ;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

it was working fine .. i tried to change the layouts and make a better design ..afterthat the problem happend .. now when i click run .. it appears on device .. and crash directly ..

Comment: please share the logcat logs

Answer (score 1):

You cannot initialize the Views before you have done setContextView.

```
final TextView        lbl1 =  (TextView)       findViewById(R.id.textView1); 
final TextView        lbl2 =  (TextView)       findViewById(R.id.textView2);
.
.
```

Move the findViewById code to `Oncreate` after call to setContentView.

Answer (score 0):

Put this code:

```
//declarations..

final TextView        lbl1 =  (TextView)       findViewById(R.id.textView1); 
final TextView        lbl2 =  (TextView)       findViewById(R.id.textView2);
final EditText        txt1 =  (EditText)       findViewById(R.id.editText1); 
final EditText        txt2 =  (EditText)       findViewById(R.id.editText2);
final Button          btn1 =  (Button)         findViewById(R.id.button1); 
final TextView        lbl3 =  (TextView)       findViewById(R.id.textView3);
```

into your `onCreate()` method.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have initialize the views before setting any layout.

It should work if you modify your code like follows:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener 
{
//declarations..

final TextView lbl1;
final TextView lbl2;
final EditText txt1;
final EditText txt2;
final Button btn1;
final TextView lbl3;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    lbl1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    lbl2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    txt1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1); 
    txt2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1); 
    lbl3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);

    // click button to get numbers from edittexts and add them to textviews ..      

    btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            ...
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not findViewByID() before OnCreate() method! so try to put those inside the Oncreate() method like this :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Button btn1= (Button)findviewById(R.id.*);
```